# how can i retrieve error messages to my java programmer from sqlserver

Tags: java, sql-server, error-handling, primary-key, buttonclick

My primary keys are `empid` and `date`. what i want to do is ones a employee inserted a values to sql server and if he tries again to insert values to database in the same day, there primary key should be conflicted. so i want to display an error if he/she tries to do like that

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
           String g = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
           if(g.equals("--Select Your Employee ID--"))
           {
           jLabel6.setForeground(Color.RED);
           jLabel6.setText("Please Select Your ID ");
           }
           else{
               jLabel6.setText("");
           }
           String a =jTextArea1.getText();
           if(a.equals("")){
                jLabel7.setForeground(Color.RED);
           jLabel7.setText("Please Fill the Report ");
           }
           else{
               jLabel7.setText("");
           }
               try{
            String url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=gym2 ";
                String username = "mali";
                String password = "12345";
                Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
                Statement st = con.createStatement ();
                ResultSet rs;
                       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String sql = "INSERT INTO report(empid,dat,rep) VALUES('"+g+"','"+format1.format(cal.getTime())+"','"+a+"')" ;
        rs= st.executeQuery(sql);
        jComboBox1.addItem("--Select Your Employee ID--");

            }
            catch(Exception e){

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go about this by adding a unique constraint on the `dat` date column in your database table.  Then SQL Server should reject any insert containing the same date since it will be a constraint violation.

Ideally, the SQL Server JDBC driver would throw an exception in this case.  If so, then you can modify your `try-catch` clause to look something like this:

```
try {
    // attempt the INSERT
}
catch (SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) {
    System.out.println("date has already been entered");
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    // handle other SQL exceptions here
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // handle generic exceptions here
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: its not working i wan to get the result to a jlable in the jframe

Answer (score 0):

Friendly way:
Do a select of the record and check if record exists. Tell the user record already exists.

Since it is a primary key duplicates will violate constraint and error will be raised and exception will be passed on to the application.